# Triggering a relay using CL100 transistor

Tags: transistors, relay

I am trying to trigger a 5V relay using a CL100 transistor using TTL logic without success. I guess using a driver transistor like BC547 in the input side of CL100 may do the trick, but I want to avoid a driver transistor and keep the circuit simple. Am I doing anything wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What voltages are on the base-emitter and collector-emitter junctions, when transistor is supposed to be "on"?

Comment: does the relay activate if you connect it between Vcc and gnd?

Comment: Possibly too high of a base resistor. This device has a Vbe_on of up to 0.9V, and their base test current is 15mA. Try 270 ohms.

Comment: How much current does the relay require to operate. I don't think you have enough base current to drive the relay here.

Comment: Coil resistance probably won't be less than about \$70\:\Omega\$ for a \$5\:\text{V}\$ relay. (They usually have a time constant around \$3\:\text{ms}\$.) This means about \$70\:\text{mA}\$. Most relays are spec'd to operate at about 70% of their rated voltage, so this means \$\ge 50\:\text{mA}\$. A BJT can be expected to saturate pretty well at \$\beta=20\$ and certainly by \$\beta=10\$. So the base current must be around \$2.5\to5.0\:\text{mA}\$. So any resistor at or below about \$1.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$ should work at the base. (This assumes, of course, that your I/O can deliver it.)

Comment: @ark1974 your question specified TTL but depending upon whether you literally mean TTL or TTL compatible  e.g. 74132 vs 74HCT132 for example the ability to source 5mA on a high output will vary. Checkout Ioh here https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1003294/NationalSemiconductor/74132/1 and here https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/956190/NXP/74HCT132/1 for examples.

Answer (score 0):

TTL is not so good at sourcing current for a high output. You'll perhaps get the ability to drive a few mA or so and the output voltage will sag.

Let's assume worst case that the logic out drops to 2.7V and you need 0.9V on the base of the CL100 the base current is going to be:

(2.7 - 0.9)/270 ~6mA for a 270 ohm resistor

The rule of thumb is you can saturate a load of 10x this or about 60mA.

So this might work if the operating current of the relay is no more than 60mA or so.

Comment: It's not working with 5V directly from the power supply.

Comment: You are putting the relay across the 5V psu and it is not clicking? Is the diode across the relay coil when you do this?

Comment: What are you using as a supply for the 5V. Have you measured the voltage without the relay and with the relay connected? If not please check.